# Handling user feature requests

Tags: intellectual-property, disclaimers

First time poster in this forum so apologies if I am not framing this question correctly. If I am in the wrong forum or you require more information please just ask before downvoting.

I am wondering about the process of implementing a feature request system for my app.
However I am wary of taking an idea from a user and then being sued by them saying that their ideas form part of my intellectual property.

What kind of legal disclaimer etc would I need to implement to prevent this being an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideas are **not** intellectual property.

- Artistic and literary works are subject to copyright.
- Branding is subject to trade mark.
- Inventions are subject to patents if applied for and granted.
- Form and function are subject to registered designs if applied for and granted.

**Ideas are subject to nothing.**

If the communication of the idea is confidential then it can't be disclosed but a feature request where the user implicitly wants it to be incorporated can't be confidential.

Comment: That's great, cheers mate